# Циклическое включение класса

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть два класса и два хедер файла соответственно:

**main_class.h**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class_1.h"

class class_1;


class main_class
{
public:

    class main_sub_class
    {

    public:

        int int_ = 555;
    };

class_1* class_1_p;
};
```

`class_1.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "main_class.h"

class main_class;


class class_1
{
public:

    std::vector<main_class>::iterator it;
    std::vector<main_class::main_sub_class>::iterator it_sub;     //Без этой строки компилируется.

};
```

Когда я включаю строчку *std::vector<main_class::main_sub_class>::iterator it_sub*, то компилятор сразу говорит, что main_class не определен.

Почему так происходит ?

Comment: класс `main_class` объявлен только предварительно. А внутренне устройство ещё не известно. `main_class::main_sub_class` можно использовать только после окончательного объявление класса. Ваше объявление файлов друг друга приводит к неопределённому порядку обработки заголовочный файлов.

Comment: решением будет убрать `#include "class_1.h"` из `main_class.h:`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, спасибо, я прошу прощения - это не полный код, я просто пытался убрать все лишнее, на самом деле в классе main_class - у меня также присутвует обьект класса class_1/

Comment: **указатель** неполного типа можно использовать.

Comment: Вопрос-дубликат не раскрывает проблему предварительной декларации вложенных классов. Ответ на ваш вопрос ближе чему-то [такому](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021809/21324434)

Comment: @needKVAS Здесь нет необходимости в предварительном объявлении вложенных классов.